# How can i get the user with id session in param request with symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to do a little API with Symfony2.

I send a session id to my controller with a URL like this:

localhost/symfony2/web/app_dev.php/users/getuser/**c5auv7mrp45rnd046cfv0vgl96**

Then, in Symfony,

```
/**
 * @Route("/getuser/{sessionId}")
 */
public function getSessionAction(Request $request, $sessionId)
{

   // Here is what i'm trying to do



    $packJson = array(
        'user_id' => $userid
    );

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData($packJson);
    return $response;
}
```

So, i would like to retrieve my user Id only with the sessionId argument.
Of course, it will be load from Db

I don't understand the logic between Session object and User Objet

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a token to identify a user. That means you have one token for each user in your database. If that is correct then it has nothing to do with sessions or a session-object.

you could simple retrieve your user with:

```
/**
 * @Route("/getuser/{token}")
 */
public function getSessionAction($token)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('token' => $token);

    $response = new JsonResponse();

    if (!$entity) {
        $response->setData('error' => 'bad token');
        return $response;
    }

    $packJson = array(
        'user_id' => $entity->getId()
    );

    $response->setData($packJson);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: ok, it seems to be cool, but i don't understand how can i generate the token ? my sessionId come from a Ajax request. How can i create a Token in Symfony and send it to my javascript app ?

Comment: I wonder what you you trying to create.
Do you need security on the API?